# How to hide tag which only part of visible in the div?

Tags: html, css

I want to hide a element that when the child width out of these parent. Such as following link.

The parent's width is fixed and it's children has one line.

when I use `overflow:hidden`, because of children's width expand parent width, the forth child show half width on the div, and another part is hidden. So ,I want to hide the forth tag.

Notice:

1. every child's width is not fixed.
2. parent's width is fixed.
3. every child must be one line, can't have a new line.

```css
.div{
  width: 180px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
} 
a {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #69a;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <a href="">test</a>
  <a href="">test</a><a href="">test</a>
  <a href="">test</a><a href="">test</a><a href="">test</a>
  <a href="">test</a><a href="">test</a><a href="">test</a>
</div>
```

## [JS Bin.](http://jsbin.com/cowaxireyu/3/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Cant seem to understand what exactly are you trying to achieve

Comment: Please include all relevant information here.

Comment: You can create the same demo here with a Snippet. No need to hide the code on an external site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force the height of the parent div, and remove the `white-space: nowrap` so the `a` tags that can't be fully dislayed will go to the next line and will be hidden by the `overflow: none;`

```css
.div{
  width: 180px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 40px;
  background: lightgrey;
} 
a {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #69a;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <a href="">test</a>
  <a href="">test</a><a href="">test</a>
  <a href="">test</a><a href="">test</a><a href="">test</a>
  <a href="">test</a><a href="">test</a><a href="">test</a>
</div>
<br />
<div class="div">
  <a href="">test test</a>
  <a href="">test test</a><a href="">test</a>
  <a href="">test</a><a href="">test</a><a href="">test</a>
  <a href="">test</a><a href="">test</a><a href="">test</a>
</div>
<br />
<div class="div">
  <a href="">te</a>
  <a href="">st</a><a href="">te</a>
  <a href="">st</a><a href="">te</a><a href="">test</a>
  <a href="">test</a><a href="">test</a><a href="">test</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. But when the child width change, this situation always, In my case, the child width is not fixed. And you create a new line, please notice the third requirement.

Comment: The new line created is not visible and won't create problem with other elements after the container `div`. Why exactly do you need the `a` elements to be on one line ? I updated the code snippet with different case of `a` width

Comment: It's a feasible solution to resolve this issue that with a fixed height to limit one line. by the way, In production, should pay attention to hidden the second line content.